# dockerfile: refer to files in directory one level above

Tags: dockerfile

I am on ubuntu. I have a Dockerfile, say in directory A.

There is another directory, say B, at same level as A.

In Dockerfile, I want to refer to files in B. I do:

```
ADD ../B/awesomescript.sh /opt/mydir/scripts
```

But this doesn't work. Docker is not able to find it.

What is then correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass context of a parent folder and
during build go downwards:

So your docker file will look like this:

```
ADD ./B/awesomescript.sh /opt/mydir/scripts
```

But *docker build* will be invoked like this:

```bash
docker build -t someimagename -f /path/to/dockerfile ../
```

Comment: Where would then I need to run this command?

Comment: I think ../ must be ./

Comment: At directory _A_, so _../_ points to the common parent directory. Where _B_ resides.